# linear subspace closed under addition

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to show that $p$ is a linear subspace of $R^n $
but I'm kinda stuck to what closed under addition means.

Given is that  $p =\{ x\in R^n | x= \alpha q + \beta r \}$
where $q \not= 0 $ and $r \not= 0$ are arbitrarily chosen vectors on $p$. Also given is that p goes through the origin.

For closed under addition I did the following:

If $u$ and $v$ are in $p$, then we have $u = \alpha_1q+\beta_1r$ and $v=\alpha_2q+\beta_2r$ 
so $u+v = \alpha_1q+\beta_1r$+$\alpha_2q+\beta_2r$ 
which we can write as $(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)q + (\beta_1+\beta_2)r$

I have no idea how this tells me if it is closed under addition.
What I see is that we add up $\alpha$ and multiply it with $q$ and add up $\beta$ multiply it with $r$ then add $q+r$ which should be in $p$. But how does that have to be in $p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p$ is the set of all things of the form $\alpha q+\beta r$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be ANY scalar. This means, assuming that the scalars are real or complex numbers, that $3q+\pi r$ is in $p$, as is $4.9q$ (in the former case, we take $\alpha=3$ and $\beta=\pi$, while in the latter case we take $\alpha=4.9$ and $\beta=0$).

The basic idea is this: The fact that $p$ is defined allows you to conclude two things:

1) Whenever we have scalars $a$ and $b$, it will follow that $aq+br$ is in $p$

2) Whenever we are told that something (say $x$) is in $p$, then we know that there MUST be some scalars $a$ and $b$ such that $x=aq+br$.

Based on what you have written, it is clear that $p$ is closed under addition.
As you pointed out, since $u$ is in $p$ it must be that $u$ is of the form $\alpha_{1}q+\beta_{1}r$, for some fixed scalars $\alpha_{1}$ and $\beta_{1}$. Similarly, we get scalars $\alpha_{2}$ and $\beta_{2}$ such that $v=\alpha_{2}q+\beta_{2}r$ (since $v\in p$). These both follow from 2) above. 
Then, since we can take $\alpha=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$ and $\beta=\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$. This shows that $u+v$ is in $p$. This follows from 1) above.

Comment: if $a$ and $b$ can be any scalar does that mean this is always closed under addition?